# Take same value from table for different variables

Tags: teradata

I'm working with Teradata and SQL and have a problem.
I have an order number, where I can have two different payers, one for  shipping, and one for the product and tax.
I want, from the order number, find the account numbers for the payers and the names for the payers.

The Order numbers and account numbers can be found in one table and then the names and account numbers can be found in another table.

Right now I have this;

```
Sellect a.order_num,
a.account_ship,
a.account_tax ||' ('||b.account_name||')' as Tax_account_name

from order a 
inner join account b
on a.account_tax = b.account_number
where a.order_num in ('1');
```

I want to be able to show the account name for the shipping account in the same way as the tax account.
Anyone having any idea?

Sorry if the question is a but confusing...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another join to the accounts table for the shipment account number:

```
Select o.order_num,
   o.account_ship,
   o.account_tax ||' ('||tax.account_name||')' as Tax_account_name
   o.account_ship ||' ('||ship.account_name||')' as Shipment_account_name
from order as o 
join account as tax  -- tax account
  on o.account_tax = tax.account_number
join account as ship -- shipment account
  on o.account_ship = ship.account_number
where o.order_num in ('1');
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!